# Mysql group by with distinct and inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

Two entities:

1. Shipment

- ShipmentId (PK)
- ShipmentTypeId
- StatusId
- EstArrivalDate

2. ShipmentItem

- ShipmentId
- ShipmentItemSeqId
- ProductId
- Quantity

I have created a join (inner join) with shipmentId and want that for each distinct productId Mysql should return only one row.

I want to find distinct products and only first record of each product

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SI.PRODUCT_ID), S.ESTIMATED_ARRIVAL_DATE, SI.QUANTITY AS SUM_QTY
FROM SHIPMENT S INNER JOIN
     SHIPMENT_ITEM SI
     ON S.SHIPMENT_ID = SI.SHIPMENT_ID AND 
        S.SHIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 'PURCHASE_SHIPMENT' AND 
        S.STATUS_ID = 'PURCH_SHIP_CREATED' AND 
        S.ESTIMATED_ARRIVAL_DATE > NOW()
GROUP BY SI.PRODUCT_ID, S.ESTIMATED_ARRIVAL_DATE, SI.QUANTITY
HAVING SI.QUANTITY > 0;
```

Please help me as this is not working.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't fully understand what you mean by "only first record of each product".

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can solve this with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select si.product_id, s.estimated_arrival_date, si.quantity as sum_qty,
        row_number() over(partition by si.product_id order by s.estimated_arrival_date) rn
    from shipment s 
    inner join shipment_item si on s.shipment_id = si.shipment_id 
    where 
        s.shipment_type_id = 'purchase_shipment' 
        and s.status_id = 'purch_ship_created' 
        and s.estimated_arrival_date > now()
) t
where rn = 1
```